# Convert random hex values to CJK characters

Tags: unicode, pseudocode

I've got a list of random hex values of 3 digits each:

```
 List<hex> hexes = "A19", "8EB", "5EF"
```

I'd like to compress them into a list of single characters that can be copied and pasted, then be decompressed later on.  For asthetic reasons, it would be nice if they were all CJK characters.

```
 HexToCharacters(hexes) --> "寏雳䠰"
 CharactersToHex("寏雳䠰") --> "A19", "8EB", "5EF"
```

Which particular CJK characters this generates isn't important, as long as they can safely make the round trip from hex to CJK back to hex.

So far, I haven't found a way to generate these characters in such a way that they are guaranteed to be in the CJK range.

(I'm using C# in my own project, but the language isn't important -- I'm just looking for a method that works.)

Comment: I think that you have 64k (0xFFFF) of hexidecimal values, but there's not that many CJK characters (around 0xBFFF).  And encoding most of those CJK characters takes ~4 bytes depending on the encoding, so this isn't a compression at all, it's the same amount of bytes as the raw data.

Comment: @MooingDuck, good point -- I'd be fine with using 3 hex digits instead of 4.

Comment: Oh, in that case simply map them to U+5000 through U+5FFF, which take two bytes each in UTF16.  Pretty much all CJK are 3 bytes in UTF8 though, so it's still not fair to call it a "compression". http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/5000-5FFF

Comment: @MooingDuck, true, this isn't actually compressing the number of bytes needed, but it is reducing the number of characters in a string representation.

Comment: If you're desiring to reduce the number of characters, also eyeball http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic + Korean characters maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, there are 4096 contiguous ideographs starting at U+3400. Simply add 0x3400 to the value and take that Unicode character.